# GO Launcher EX: widget lost after reboot

Tags: app-widgets, reboot, launcher, go-launcher-ex

Whenever I reboot, widget get lost in GO Launcher EX.
how can I fix this?

NB: the widget is on the internal memory

Comment: Have you reported it to the developer in question of the said widget? Or posted on Go Launcher's forum?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a solution, but I have this problem also and have a couple piece of information to add. Go Launcher and apps associated with widgets are installed on internal memory. Here's what's strange: 1. the Widgetsoid widget in the notifications area always comes back upon a reboot, but the homescreen widgets do not 2. the GO Calendar/Agenda widget (downloaded as a stand-alone, but requires GO Launcher) always shows after a reboot, but the GO SMS widget (came with the GO SMS app) does not I suspect there is an issue with GO Launcher not initializing homescreens properly. That's just m

Comment: From another user: "Go Launcher and apps associated with widgets are installed on internal memory.  The Widgetsoid widget in the notifications area always comes back upon a reboot, but the homescreen widgets do not
the GO Calendar/Agenda widget (downloaded as a stand-alone, but requires GO Launcher) always shows after a reboot, but the GO SMS widget (came with the GO SMS app) does not
I suspect there is an issue with GO Launcher not initializing homescreens properly. That's just my 2-cents. I'd love to hear if someone actually knows what's going on. Thanks."

Answer (score 2):

Is your widget application installed to the SD card? If yes, then that is the problem. When the phone reboots, it takes a few minutes for the SD card to get loaded. This causes an issue for any widgets that are not installed to the internal memory as they aren't available when the phone first boots up, causing them to not load.

So, please verify the widget app is installed to internal memory instead of the SD card.

This is what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: thank you, but the widget is on the internal memory!

Comment: @iask Does the same problem happen if you use a different home launcher than GO?

Comment: nope, it seems to happen with this launcher only

Comment: Worked for me, app NinjaCam